# Jenkins Email Notifications go to Outlook Junk folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, jenkins

I was wondering why some of Jenkins Job's Email Notifications (I use Editable Email Notification) go to the Outlook Junk folder (for all users) and not to the Inbox folder?

Comment: Because Outlook thinks they are spam?

Comment: David, only some of the Jenkins notification go to the Junk and some not ...

Comment: So what is the difference between the ones that do and the ones that don't? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: No difference  ... simply some go into Inbox and some into Junk

Comment: Then see my answer to stop it happening.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm wondering if there's general solution for all users. Such that won't need each user to the Outlook change.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Jenkins Email Notifications go to Outlook Junk folder

Add your Jenkins email sender address(es) to the **Safe Senders List**.

---

**Junk Email Filter Lists**

> While the Junk Email Filter checks your incoming messages automatically, the Junk Email Filter Lists give you more control over what is considered spam. You can add names, email addresses and domains to these lists so the Filter allows for messages from sources that you trust, or blocks messages that arrive from specific email addresses and domains that you don't know or trust.

**Safe Senders List**

> **Email addresses and domain names in the Safe Senders List are never treated as junk email, regardless of the content of the message. You can add your Contacts and other correspondents to this list.** If you use a Microsoft Exchange Server account, all names and addresses in the global address list (GAL) are automatically considered safe.

Source [Overview of the Junk Email Filter](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-the-Junk-Email-Filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089?CorrelationId=3d5c689f-eb61-42fa-bd25-9b49964239bb&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

---

#### Add trusted names to the Safe Senders or Safe Recipients Lists

> By adding email addresses and domain names that you trust to the Safe
>   Senders List, you instruct Outlook that messages from those sources
>   are never to be considered as junk. If you belong to mailing lists or
>   distribution lists, you can add these names to your Safe Recipients
>   List.
>
> To add a person to the Safe Senders List, click a message from the
>   sender. On the Home tab, in the Delete group, click Junk, and then
>   click Never Block Sender.
>
> To add a specific address or domain to the Safe Recipients List, click
>   a message from the sender. On the Home tab, in the Delete group, click
>   Junk, and then click Never Block the Group or Mailing List.
>
> To manually add names or domains to these lists, do the following:
>
> 1. On the Home tab, in the Delete group, click Junk, and then click Junk E-mail Options.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    - To add safe senders, on the Safe Senders tab, click Add.
>    - To add safe recipients, on the Safe Recipients tab, click Add.
>
>      [image]
> 3. In the Enter an e-mail address or Internet domain name to be added to the list box, enter the name or address that you want to add.
>      For example, you can add :
>
>    - a specific email address, such as someone@example.com
>    - an Internet domain, such as @example.com, or example.com.
> 4. Click OK and repeat for each entry that you want to add.
>
>    - If you want all Contacts to be considered safe senders, select the Also trust e-mail from my Contacts check box in the Safe
>        Senders tab.
>    - Some people whom you correspond to might not be listed in your Contacts. If you want all such people to be considered as safe
>        senders, select the Automatically add people I e-mail to the Safe
>        Senders List check box.
>    - If you have existing lists of safe names and addresses, you can move that information into Outlook. Click Import from File and
>        browse for the list file that you want. To create a file that uses
>        your current list, click Export to File and then specify where you
>        want the new file saved.
>    - To change a name on either list, click the name that you want to change and then click Edit. To remove a name, click the name that
>        you want and then click Remove.
>    - If you are using a Microsoft Exchange Server account, all of the names and email addresses that are in your organization's address
>        book — also known as the Global Address List — are automatically
>        considered safe.

Source [Add names to the Junk Email Filter lists](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Add-names-to-the-Junk-Email-Filter-lists-98b3c0f2-81aa-46cc-b198-20b9faa9e831)

---

#### I'm wondering if there's general solution for all users?

Add your Jenkins email sender address(es) to the **Global Address List**.

> If you are using a Microsoft Exchange Server account, all of the names and email addresses that are in your organization's address
>   book — also known as the Global Address List — are automatically
>   considered safe.